# R - Custom X axis using CSV data

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am playing around with RStudio and have a question about customizing my x-axis. In my current project, I want to plot the date on the X axis and the grade this certain action received on the Y.

```
tree <- read.csv(file="D:/R_Work/average_grade.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

plot(tree$NUM,tree$AVG,
     main="YSLOW Grades",
     xlab="Date",
     ylab="Grade",
     xaxt="n",
     yaxt="n",
     ylim = c(5,0))


axis(1, at = seq(tree$DATE), las=2)
axis(2, at=1:5, labels=LETTERS[1:5])
```

What I am trying to do as you can see from my code is plot NUM vs AVG, NUM being the number assigned with an action. However, I want NUM to show up as DATE on my actual graph x-axis. So instead of a number it will show the corresponding date. I am trying to do this with my second to last line of code but it does not work for me (not surprisingly, was just testing anything). DATE is associated with a CSV file containing data like 7.10.14 and so on.

The reason I am not simply plotting DATE vs AVG is that when I plot the date, weird horizontal lines are plotted perpendicular to my data points. I figured there is an easy work around but can't solve it myself.

Graph (with weird lines):
[image]

If anyone has any idea how to edit my x axis to coincide with my CSV data points or how to remove those lines so I can easily plot a date like the image shows that would be great.

Thanks!

Data:

DATE,AVG,NUM

7.13.14,2,1

7.14.9,2,2

7.15.10,2,3

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data using `dput(tree)` or `dput(head(tree))` if it's a large dataset?

Comment: Should we assume that 7.13.14 is 13 Jul 2014; 7.14.9 is 14 Jul 2009; and 7.15.10 is 15 July 2010?  I"m not sure I understand the date format.

Comment: @Benjamin The format is Month.Day.Hour

Comment: @NickKennedy Hi Nick, I posted my CSV file underneath my question. Hopefully this helps. Originally I had solely DATE and AVG but as you can see from the graph, it graphs the dates in a weird manner. My whole idea by adding "NUM" would be to use those as X coordinates to have it properly graph, and then simply use DATE as what the viewer would see on the axis. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help you get where you want to be?

```
tree <- "DATE,AVG,NUM
7.13.14,2,1
7.14.9,2,2
7.16.10,2,3"

tree <- read.csv(textConnection(tree),
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tree$DATE_NEW <- as.POSIXct(paste0("2015.", tree$DATE),
                         format = "%Y.%m.%d.%H")

plot(as.numeric(factor(tree$DATE_NEW)),
     tree$AVG,
     main="YSLOW Grades",
     xlab="Date",
     ylab="Grade",
     xaxt="n",
     yaxt="n",
     ylim = c(5,0))

axis(1, at = factor(tree$DATE_NEW), 
     labels = format(tree$DATE_NEW,
                     format = "%b %d %H:%S"))
axis(2, at=1:5, labels=LETTERS[1:5])
```

EDITS:

The big change is that I am plotting `as.numeric(factor(tree$DATE_NEW))`.  When you plot a factor on the x-axis, R tries to plot a boxplot by default.  And since you only have one observation per factor group, you see a single line (the quartiles and median are all identical).

What we needed to do to get the plot you wanted was plot the underlying numerical value of the factor.  It's a bit ugly, but now the dots are all evenly spaced (ignoring the time elapsed between them) and still showing dots instead of lines.

Comment: Thanks Ben this helps a lot this is just what I wanted. Is it possible to keep format like 7.13.14 and not include the month?

Comment: See `?strptime` for the many, many ways you can format the appearance with a date/time object.  The pattern is `format(DATE, format = [your desired format string]`.  In the example, `%b %d %H:%S` gives month, day, hours, and seconds.  looking at `?strptime` you can find that `%d %H:%S` would give the days, hours and seconds only.  That is an enormously helpful help-file.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. I have come to realize that when I plot many values that differ my X axis becomes spaced out poorly. For instance, if I have 3 dates all within a day of each other, then one from a week later, the three dates will be clumped up together and the 4th will be much farther down on the X axis. Is there any way to have all dates be evenly spaced no matter their value? I've tried researching strptime but have had no luck.

Comment: You need to change the class of your x, variable.  If you convert it from a date to a factor, it should plot the way you want it.

Comment: Factoring does help as it does space out all my points. However, now I am getting those lines like before in my graph and also the date formatting is now somewhat weird. Not sure how to make this work 100%. Instead of using this date object, is there a simple way to just read my CSV file that already contains the dates, and have the X axis simply read and print those dates? Basically, no matter what is in the date column of CSV, have x axis print that out with corresponding grades.

Comment: Made an edit and added explanation there.  Although it may not be in your interests yet, some of the problems we ran into in this example can be avoided with `ggplot2` where fewer assumptions are made about what kind of plot you want.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Sure a bit ugly but it does the trick! ggplot2 is something I have been meaning to look into although for now your solution works.